# Toolbar at the bottom in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

I want to create simple CoordinatorLayout with RecyclerView and Toolbar, but the difference from standard solution is that Toolbar should be at the bottom, and should disappear when RecyclerView is scrolling to the bottom.

So I created simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Of course Toolbar is on the top instead at the bottom. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Wow, that's a cool idea, not sure about that but you could try to do this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:id="@+id/main_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/my_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But honestly I don't believe that's enough.

Maybe the solution is to give the `Toolbar` a custom `app:layout_behavior` as you would normally do with a FAB as I do in [my blog article](https://medium.com/@beraldofilippo/android-coordinatorlayout-scroll-aware-fab-f0c6264a5ed1#.yl5le7q2r).

Please let me know how it turns out!

EDIT

I've just realized that maybe what you're looking for is the newly introduced [bottom navigation bar](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs)!
I saw that there are plenty of third party libs that do that out-of-the-box or maybe try to implement it you own!

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible with your solution, cause I get ClassCastException, second thing in xml should be RecyclerView.

Comment: Oh, if I remember well CoordinatorLayout is a subclass of FrameLayout, you can swap elements inside the xml block without side effects i guess. Please see my edit also!

Comment: Oh I was wrong, it was temporary error, now toolbar is at the bottom and I'm trying to find solution for hide/show with scrolling. I don't want to use bottom navigation bar cause items on toolbar should open new activity instead of new replacing fragment in container. I mean, already created libs for bottom navigation bar are too big for my solution, but maybe I will have to use them.

Comment: I understand, try to give the Toolbar an app:layout_behavior though, and see what happens ;)

Comment: you mean app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" ?

Comment: Please take a look to the blog article. You should create a new class MyScrollAwareToolbarBehavior sublassing CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<Toolbar> similarly to the one there and then assign it to the toolbar with app:layout_behavior=”com.mypackage.behaviors.MyScrollAwareToolbarBehavior” and see if it works. Maybe its worth a shot since it's not too much work to do

Comment: Seems it could work ! But do you know how to hide and show Toolbar with animation ?

Comment: I've never experimented much with animation, the slip in / slip out animation was enough for my case ;) please let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/my_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Remember that I want toolbar at the bottom !

Comment: Use this in toolbar android:layout_gravity="bottom"

Comment: Toolbar is still on the top